Finite expected stopping time
Let $T$ be a stopping time, and suppose there exist $N, \varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $n$, $\mathbb{P}(T \leq n + N \mid \mathcal{F}_n) > \varepsilon$ almost surely. Then $\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty$.
This lemma appears in multiple sources, e.g. the book "probability and martingales" where it says "whatever always stand a reasonable chance of happening will almost surely happen, sooner rather than later". I've spent a lot of time thinking about this, but for some reason I just can't understand the intuition behind it. Conditional probability is saying, given $\mathcal{F}_n$ which will "shine light" on the black box $\omega$ and offer partial information about $\omega$, what is the new probability that $\omega \in \{T \leq n + N\}$ given this information. But what on earth is the intuition behind $\mathbb{P}(T \leq n + N \mid \mathcal{F}_n) > \varepsilon$ almost surely for every $n$? What thing has a reasonable chance of happening? Why will it happen sooner and not later? Can someone give me a plain english explanation of this?

$\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(T < \infty) = 1$, so "it will almost surely happen". Something has a reasonable chance to happen if the probability is bigger than some $\varepsilon$. So, if at any time $n$ there is a reasonable chance that it will happen in the near future of time $n$ (maximum $N$ steps away, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(T \leq n + N \ | \ \mathcal{F}_n) > \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) then it will happen almost surely (since then $\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty$). It will happen sooner rather than later because by Markov's inequality $\mathbb{P}(T > T_0) \leq \mathbb{E}(T)/T_0$ which is small for large times $T_0$.

The condition $\Bbb P(T\le n+N)>\epsilon$ means that no matter what has happened so far (up to time $n$) the chance, if $T>n$, that $T$  will occur soon (before $N$ more ticks of the clock) is uniformly positive.
As you know from Probability With Martingales, the condition is rather strong. It implies that
$$
\Bbb P(T>kN)\le (1-\epsilon)^k, \qquad k=1,2,\ldots,
$$
so not only is $\Bbb E(T)<\infty$ but $\Bbb E(T^m)<\infty$ for all positive integers $m$; even $\Bbb E(e^{\alpha T})<\infty$ for small enough $\alpha>0$.
Contrast the above  situation with a simple symmetric random walk $(S_n)$ and $T$ the first positive time the walk hits $0$. The conditional probability $\Bbb P(T\le n+N\mid S_n=x)$ decays to $0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, and so a strictly positive uniform lower bound on $\Bbb P(T\le n+N\mid \mathcal F_n)$ is impossible.
